# Was Bilbo's sexuality ever referred to by Tolkien?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, sexuality

Bilbo is certainly known to be a confirmed bachelor, a fact which over the years has resulted in not a few suggestions that he might be gay. [GLReview](http://www.glreview.org/article/the-tolkien-in-bilbo-baggins/), for example, describes a key theme of the Hobbit as being ...

> ... The distinctly homoerotic yearnings of Bilbo Baggins

With that in mind, are there any insights or canonical references in any of Tolkien's works (including the LOTR and Hobbit novels, supplementary works or even Tolkien's personal letters, interviews and other sources) that indicate in which way Bilbo was sexually inclined? i.e. Did he ever show a sexual interest in a woman (or a man, for that matter), regardless of whether he then acted on that attraction.

Comment: Why would you care?

Comment: *"that he was a confirmed bachelor"* sure, absolutely, *"and maybe a virgin as well"* .... zuh?  where do you pull that from?

Comment: If he was actually gay, or Tolkien wanted him to be gay, he could actually be the first gay fantasy hero.  That's something!

Comment: @Radhil, Correct me if I am wrong, but Bilbo didn't date at all.

Comment: @KDog - well, his history beyond the family heritage of "there has always been a Baggins at Bag End" isn't really covered other than in broad strokes.  Sex life or romance is simply omitted, and I vaguely think Frodo is covered the same way.  Sam is seemingly the only one in the gang with intentions, crushing on Rosie, although I know the tale of years has more.  The Baggins' could be interpreted any way any reader wishes.

Comment: Why would indifference be rare in a society modeled after the age of British gentlemen, sans all scarcity, in which a man is expected to reach middle age before he is even considered an adult?

Comment: @Axelrod, that was just repression, pure and simple.

Comment: Bilbo, a true iconoclast, in more ways than one.

Comment: @KDog - I was a bachelor for many years because I couldn't stand most women I met.  My wife would chuckle at the idea I was homosexual.  It's a distinct possibility among many, but it feels like you're projecting the answer you want a bit.

Comment: @Radhil As was I, not marrying until 36.  However, there was plenty of other evidence that I wasn't homosexual.  Not true in Bilbo's case.

Comment: Why all the down votes people?  There is nothing wrong with Bilbo being gay.

Comment: No. But but voting is also based on the merit of a question, whether there's been research, etc. This question looks like more of an attempt at discussion.

Comment: The community tends to take a dim view of making assumptions about a character's sexuality based on an absence of displayed romantic interest; one of our lowest-voted questions is "Is Captain America gay?" and the foundation for that question is, essentially, "he displays no romantic interest in the many beautiful women he works with". There's no fundamental difference between that question and yours

Comment: I wonder why? Realism is important in world-building and homo-eroticism in literature is often discussed.  See Moby Dick or Billy Budd for examples.

Comment: @KDog: I think the primary difference is discussing what's actually there versus saying "well, there's no real evidence... but what if they were?" especially when it boils down to "well, they don't act like *I'd* expect a heterosexual male to act, so they must be gay, right?" :)

Comment: @KDog You may not think there's anything wrong with being gay but Tolkien was a fairly religious Catholic. There were no gays in the Shire!

Comment: I've done an absolutely enormous edit on this question in an attempt to drag it away from being quite so heavily opinion-based (and polarising). If you feel I've gone too far, feel free to click the rollback button to take it back to its prior form

Comment: Oh well, I've gotten it reopened. Can't do a damn thing about the downvotes ;-(

Comment: @JasonBaker IMO, the primary difference is that there are many fewer (if any) feasible women for bilbo to even take an interest in.

Answer (score 24):

### Bilbo was almost certainly intended by Tolkien to be heterosexual

In the very first draft of *The Fellowship of the Ring*, Tolkien wrote that Bilbo dropped out of Hobbit society in order to get married and have little hobbitlings - one of whom would grow up to become the protagonist of the book:

> [Bilbo] said this very loud and everybody sat up who could. 'Goodbye! I am going away after dinner. Also I am going to get married.'
>
> *[...]*
>
> That's that. It merely serves to explain that Bilbo Baggins got married and had many children, because I am going to tell you a story about one of his descendants, and if you had only read his memoirs up to the date of Balin's visit - ten years at least before this birthday party - you might have been puzzled.
>
> <sup>*The History of Middle-earth* VI *The Return of the Shadow* Part I: "The First Phase" Chapter 1: "A Long-Expected Party" *(i) The First Version*</sup>

This version was swiftly abandoned, but the third draft introduces Bingo Baggins, Frodo's literary forebear, as the son of Bilbo, and says that Bilbo had gotten married at age seventy-one:

> When Bingo, son of Bilbo, of the well-known Baggins family, prepared to celebrate his [fifty-fifth >] seventy-second birthday there was some talk in the neighbourhood, and people polished up their memories. *[...]* [Bilbo] did two more things that caused tongues to wag: he got married when seventy-one (a little but not too late for a hobbit), choosing a bride from the other side of the Shire<sup>1</sup>, and giving a wedding-feast of memorable splendour; he disappeared (together with his wife) shortly before his hundred-and-eleventh birthday, and was never seen again.
>
> <sup>*The History of Middle-earth* VI *The Return of the Shadow* Part I: "The First Phase" Chapter 1: "A Long-Expected Party" *(iii) The Third Version*</sup>

Bilbo's marriage would be abandoned in the next draft, with Bingo shifting to Bilbo's nephew, where he would remain. Christopher Tolkien remarks in his commentary on the chapter that he thought the abandonment of Bilbo's marriage to be "inevitable", but doesn't discuss why.

Regardless, the published *Lord of the Rings* contains no references to this original concept; at no point does Bilbo express any romantic interest in any character, male or female. His reasons for remaining a bachelor are discussed in *Unfinished Tales*, where Gandalf remarks (emphasis mine):

> I guessed that he wanted to remain 'unattached' for some reason deep down which he did not understand himself - or would not acknowledge, for it alarmed him. **He wanted, all the same, to be free to go [leave the Shire and have adventures] when the chance came**, or he had made up his courage. I remembered how he used to pester me with questions when he was a youngster about the Hobbits that had occasionally 'gone off,' as they said in the Shire.
>
> <sup>*Unfinished Tales* Part 3: "The Third Age" Chapter III: "The Quest of Erebor"</sup>

I'll grant that you can read this passage, particularly the first sentence, as a metaphor for deeply repressed homosexuality in a homophobic time. But I would say that the rest of the passage (coupled with Tolkien's early drafts) rather puts paid to that reading: Bilbo never marries because, subconsciously if nothing else<sup>2</sup>, he wants to be free to go have adventures.

It's worth noting that it isn't unprecedented for characters in Middle-earth to remain unmarried. Even among Hobbits, there are several with no children ([Isengrim III](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Isengrim_Took_III) springs to mind), which doesn't *necessarily* preclude marriage but does hint in that direction, and still more with no spouses or children listed in the family tree (such as [Dora Baggins](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Dora_Baggins)). There's at least one Hobbit, [Ferumbras III](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Ferumbras_III), who is known to have never married; his mother was so unpleasant that he was allegedly unable to find anyone willing to cohabitate with her<sup>3</sup>:

> Her son, *Ferumbras*, had no wife, being unable (it was alleged) to find anyone willing to occupy apartments in the Great Smials, under the rule of Lalia.
>
> <sup>*The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien* 214: To A.C. Nunn (draft)</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Later in the draft, Tolkien reveals that Bilbo married Primula Brandybuck; interestingly, Primula would remain as Frodo's mother, though her husband was changed to Drogo, a cousin of Bilbo's

<sup>2</sup> And possibly part of the design of [Ilúvatar](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Iluvatar)

<sup>3</sup> A peculiar quirk of the Took clan is that the entire family lived in a single, massive Hobbit-house: Great Smials

Comment: I fear that Victorian repression was alas at work here.

Comment: Didn't Bilbo dislike pretty much everyone he knew?

Comment: He was a bit of a loner, even among all those Dwarves

Comment: @amaranth He wasn't fond of the Sackville-Bagginses, but he seems amiable at best, ambivalent at worst with the other attendees of the Party. He's at least friendly with the Gamgees, though they'd be too low-class for marrying

Comment: @KDog: Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence, but there's no evidence to support the supposition of Bilbo Baggins having homosexual leanings.

Comment: I would read this long and hard.  It has some very good insight into the matter of asexuality in Tolkien and even addresses Frodo's sexuality and many others. http://www.ansereg.com/warm_beds_are_good.htm

Comment: Actually in Letter 43, Tolkien does discuss asexuality.

Comment: @KDog I just re-read Letter 43 to refresh my memory, and I do not believe it means what you think it means. Regardless, this is not the place for a detailed discussion on Tolkien's general opinions on sex

Comment: @JasonBaker I would read the link from warm beds are good, well the link to the PDF embedded therein, it has the direct quote.  Quite a well written essay to tell you the truth.

Comment: http://www.ansereg.com/WarmBedsareGood.pdf  is a direct link to the PDF, hallway down the page

Answer (score -1):

I believe him to be Heterosexual but because of his adventures he is given a wider perspective of the the world outside the shire and has experienced things that his fellow hobbits just can't mentally grasp, therefore cannot connect with anyone within it. Try to think of it as a vet trying to readjust to normal life but can't completely as in regards to socialising with others, he is a recluse, always working on his book, which is probably his form of therapy. So my answer is "No, I don't think Bilbo is gay, I think he suffers from PTSD."

Comment: Do you have any evidence of this?

Comment: Froda suffers from more PTSD than Bilba (with the corrected masculine forms of their names — heh).  See to the first link mentioned [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/89995/68218) — quite a bit to scroll down, but it is there.